# The Sifra on peace

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, commentaries, bechukosai, shalom-peace

The Sifra in Parshas Bechukosi says, *"Peace is the seal of all blessings, because without peace, prosperity, health, food, and drink are worthless."*

Does anyone know where I can find the Sifra in Parshas Bechukosi online?

Comment: Do you have access to a Sifra? If you've already narrowed it down to the parsha, you should be able to find it in short order. If you don't have access to a Sifra, might I ask why you want a specific citation?

Comment: Please [edit] in why you think that the Sifra says these exact words despite the fact that you apparently 
haven't seen it inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Sifra* says ([*B'chukosai* 1:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38154&st=&pgnum=114)):

> שמא תאמרו הרי מאכל והרי משתה אם אין שלום אין כלום ת"ל ונתתי שלום בארץ מגיד שהשלום שקול כנגד הכל וכן הוא אומר עושה שלום ובורא רע מגיד שהשלום שקול כנגד הכל

Translation:

> Lest you say [after reading the blessings of abundance mentioned in [*Vayikra* 26:4-5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0326.htm#4)], "There is food, there is drink, but if there is no peace, there is nothing." Therefore the verse comes to say ([*Vayikra* 26:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0326.htm#6)), "And I will give peace in the land." This tells you that peace is equivalent to everything. And it likewise says ([*Y'sha'ya* 45:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1045.htm#7)), "I make peace, and I create evil." This tells you that peace is weighed as comparable to everything.

This *Sifra* is also cited by [Rashi on *Vayikra* 26:6](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=3&perek=26&mefaresh=rashi) ([English translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9927#showrashi=true)).